# Что означает использование ? и : в коде?

Tags: java, android

Есть такая строчка кода:

```
 item.addProperty(SoapScheme.ROUTES.Item.OUTLET_CODE, route.outlet == null ? 0 : route.outlet.code);
```

Интересует, что означает `?` и `:`, то-есть интересует, что именно означает это выражение  `route.outlet == null ? 0 : route.outlet.code`  ?

Comment: это тернерная операция ( условие ? выполнить если да : выполнить если нет)

Comment: тернарный оператор который заменяет оператор условия `if`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Это [тернарная условная операция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Если `route.outlet == null` - истина, то возвращается значение после знака `?`, если ложь, то значение после `:`.

Answer (score 12):

Тернарный оператор (или как уже было написано выше тернарный условный оператор).

По сути, этот кусочек кода можно было бы переписать так примерно так

```
if(route.outlet == null) {
    temp = 0;
}
else {
    temp = route.outlet.code;
}
item.addProperty(SoapScheme.ROUTES.Item.OUTLET_CODE, temp);
```