# Помогите разобрать строку кода

Tags: java, if

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    words.add(reader.readLine());

Map<String, Integer> map = countWords(words);
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : map.entrySet())
     System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());


public static Map<String, Integer> countWords(ArrayList<String> list){
    HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String word: list) 
        result.put(word, result.containsKey(word) ? result.get(word) + 1: 1);
}
```

расшифруйте, пожалуйста, вот эту строку:

```
result.put(word, result.containsKey(word) ? result.get(word) + 1: 1);
```

Comment: Вы не знаете что такое тернарный оператор? или что такое Map?

Comment: Тернарный оператор - почитаю, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Или дубль [Что означает использование ? и : в коде?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564168/191482) ....на выбор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result.put(word    , result.containsKey(word) ? result.get(word) + 1: 1);
```

тут `word` - это твой ключ, а значение которое ему присвоится расшифровывается вот так

```
if (result.containsKey(word)){
    // значение будет
    result = result.get(word) + 1;
else{
    result = 1;
}
```

Такая конструкция называется одностроковое условие

```
result.containsKey(word) ? result.get(word) + 1 : 1
```

создается с помощью оператора **?**

вот пример:

```
условие ? значение1 : значение2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Это тернарный оператор**

если `result.containsKey(word) = true`, то результат равен `result.get(word) + 1`, в обратном случае `1`.

Comment: вроде понятно, а что значит первое слово word в скобках?

Comment: у тебя вначале ArrayList<String> words и туда ты заносишь данные. Потом в for (String word: list) ты эти данные разбиваешь на отдельные куски

Comment: Почитайhttp://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/hashmap.php

Comment: там про HashMap

Answer (score 0):

result - это словарь, где ключ word, а значение кол-во таких слов на текущий момент. 
в строчке

```
result.put(word    , result.containsKey(word) ? result.get(word) + 1: 1);
```

мы апдейтим значение для ключа word. Если `result.containsKey(word)`, тогда  пишем "уже подсчитанное кол-во слов" + 1, если такого слова еще не было, то проставлем ему единицу. В конце цикла подсчитаем кол-во для каждого слова в списке (который подается на вход метода).