# преобразовать for в виде jstl тега

Tags: java, jstl

нужна помощь, заменил данную конструкцию

```
<% for (int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) - 2; i <= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) + 2;i++) {
  if(i > 0) { %>
    <li class="li1">
      <a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=<%= i %>><%= i %></a>
    </li‌​>
  <% }
} %>
```

на такую

```
<c:forEach var = "i" begin = "${page-2}" end = "${page+2}">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${i > 0}">
      <li class="li1">
        <a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=${i}>${i}</a>
      </li>
    </c‌​:when>
  </c:choose>
</c‌​:forEach>
```

приложение перестало работать корректно, что я сделал не так, в jstl новенький, помогите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<c:set var="firstPageNum" scope="request" value="${ param.page - 2 }" />
<c:set var="lastPageNum" scope="request" value="${ empty param.page ? 3 : param.page + 2 }" />
<c:forEach var="i" begin="${ firstPageNum > 0 ? firstPageNum : 1 }" end="${ lastPageNum }">
    <li class="li1">
        <a class="a2" href="SkisqlController?action=list&page=${i}">${i}</a>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: спасибо, вроде бы как работает, но есть одно но, первая страница то не выводит все данные, то не рисует в меню странички (2,3,4,5), а со скриплетами первая страница работала нормально, интересно в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Код вывода данных я вообще не видел, не могу ничего сказать. Приведённый вами код вывода страниц может ничего не печатать только в том случае, если странице не передан параметр `page`.

Comment: судя по атрибутам `request` `page` передается при переходе на первую страницу, да и я так думаю если бы `page` не передавался, то и остальные страницы бы не работали.

Comment: ну и опять же 
`<% for (int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) - 2; i <= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) + 2;i++) {
  if(i > 0) { %>
    <li class="li1">
      <a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=<%= i %>><%= i %></a>
    </li‌​>
  <% }
} %>` этот код то работает корректно

Comment: Попробуйте изменённый вариант.

Comment: спасибо, работает, а можете немного объяснить как оно правильно работает? например эта часть `{ empty param.page ? 3 : param.page + 2 }` я просто в этом варианте не вижу `if`

Comment: Это [тернарный оператор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564169/204271).

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)